# How can I get python to read every nth line of a .txt file?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

If I wanted python to read every 2nd (or every 4th) line of a file, how could I tell it to do so? Additionally, if I wanted to read line 2 of a .txt file, but every 4 lines after that (next line would be line 6, then 10, and so on forth), how could I make it do so?

Answer (score 14):

You can't... [do it using pure I/O functions] You have to read all lines and simply make your code ignore the lines that you do not need.

For example:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
desired_lines = lines[start:end:step]
```

In the code above replace start, end, and step with desired values, e.g., *"...if I wanted to read line 2 of a .txt file, but every 4 lines after that..."* you would do like this:

```
desired_lines = lines[1::4]
```

Comment: Downvoted because of the statement: *"You have to read all lines and simply make your code ignore the lines that you do not need"*. Not true and not necessary, see other answers here... This creates ***two*** unnecessary lists

Comment: Thank you, AGN Gazer. Your answer saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party, but here is a solution that doesn't require to read the whole file contents into RAM at once, which might cause trouble when working with large enough files:

```
# Print every second line.
step = 2
with open("file.txt") as handle:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(handle):
        if lineno % step == 0:
            print(line)
```

File objects (`handle`) allow to iterate over lines. This means we can read the file line by line without accumulating all the lines if we don't need to. To select every *n*-th line, we use the modulo operator with the current line number and the desired step size.

Comment: This will fail for the second example of *start from line 2 and take every 4 lines*. You would expect to take line 6, but `6 % 4 != 0`...

Comment: This prints the first line, third line, etc because enumerate starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can first `open` the `file` as `f` with a `with` statement. Then, you can `iterate` through every `line` in the `file` using Python's `slicing` notation.

If we take `f.read()`, we get a `string` with a `new-line` (`\n`) character at the end of every `line`:

```
"line1\nline2\nline3\n"
```

so to convert this to a `list` of `lines` so that we can `slice` it to get every other `line`, we need to `split` it on each occurrence of `\n`:

```
f.read().split()
```

which for the above example will give:

```
["line1", "line2", "line3"]
```

Finally, we need to get every-other `line`, this is done with the `slice` `[::2]`. We know this from the way that `slicing` works:

```
list[start : stop : step]
```

Using all this, we can write a `for-loop` which will `iterate` through every-other `line`:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split("\n")[::2]:
        print(line)
```

Comment: I do not know why your answer was down-voted but I can reassure you it was not me.

Comment: @AGNGazer Don't worry, I wasn't accusing anyone, I just wanted to see what someone thought was not useful about it... A downvote without a comment isn't that helpful

Comment: Probably the fact that this reads the whole file into a string instead of iterating the file line-by-line...

Answer (score -3):

Another way to solve this problem,

```
def readFile(lineNo):
    with open("read.txt", "r") as ins:
        array = []
        for line in ins:
            array.append(line)
        for i in range(1, len(array)):
            print(array[i*lineNo - 1])
readFile(2)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Python doesn't use `arrays`, it uses `lists`, and this just won't work...

Comment: You also need a space between the end of the `function` definition and the call to the `function`...

Comment: it is just name of variable, have you tried executing this code?

Comment: Yes, it fails in many ways... And I know its just a `variable` name, but it just shows a lack of understanding, that's all.

Comment: can you give me example where it fails?

Comment: Well it will give an `IndexError` even if you leave a line before the call to the function. This is because you are adding all the lines in the `file` to a `list` and then `iterating` through every `index` in this `list`. Then, you try to get the value from the list of that `index` multiplied by the input. This means that unless the input is `1`, you are going to be trying to get an element in the list which is way over the end - giving an `IndexError`. You can fix the error by making the second `for-loop` go to `len(array)/lineNo`. Nevertheless, atm your code does not work as I said.