# How to skip the first two lines of a file and read those lines that are multiple of 5

Tags: python, file

I have a file and I want to skip the first two lines and read those lines that are multiple of 5

line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4 
line 5
line 6 
line 7 
line 8 
line 9 
line 10

output:
line 3
line 8
..
.
.

Comment: Why does your sample output include line 3?  3 isn't a multiple of 5.

Comment: because he is reading lines 3+5*k?

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get python to read every nth line of a .txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062493/how-can-i-get-python-to-read-every-nth-line-of-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file and then filter it.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f.readlines()

lines = [x.strip() for x in f][2::5]
```

Comment: I think `lines[2::5]` is a quicker equivalent to your final line.

Comment: You are right. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `next` to iterate over the file manually. This won’t read the whole file into memory, which is good if the file is large.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = []
    f = iter(f)
    next(f)
    next(f)
    while True:
        try:
            lines.append([next(f) for _ in range(5)][-1])
        except StopIteration:
            break
```